# Binding a DataList to an object's method instead of a property

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Thing() { 
    ...
  }

  ...

}
```

If I have an `IList<Person>` that I'm using as a data source for a DataList control, and the DataList looks like this:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" ID="Profiles">
    <ItemTemplate>                                  
        <%#Eval("Name") %>          
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

How do I replace the `Name` property of the data source with a call to the data source object's `Thing()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%#((Person)Container.DataItem).Thing()%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use properties.  The property will be "Name" (or whatever) and the "Getter" on this property will be the method you wish to use to generate the value.   While you *can* call a function from here, I think it would be better design to use a property.

Comment: I can't just "use a property" - the code I posted was simplified in the interests of making the question clear. In reality, changing the method to a property is not a viable option.

Comment: Ok - just trying to be helpful as this is, generally, the preferred route.  Good luck with the remainder of you problem.